# Android USB Connection to computer malfunctions after being connected to the ADK with the DemoKit app

Tags: android, usb, adk

ADK and DemoKit are working perfectly.

However, when plugged back into the computer the phone reports "USB Debugging Connected" but no "USB Connected".

I then get no USB Storage and no ADB connection.
Problem resolves after rebooting the device.

I'm using a Nexus S with CyanogenMod 7.1.

Ideas?